# Deleting email addresses from list

Tags: civimail

Some people have asked to be removed from our email list.  How do I do that? I've tried just deleting the name but I can't make it permanent

Comment: Please EDIT your question (not add info in a comment) to include more information.  The standard info you should always include is CiviCRM version and CMS type and version. For this question you should also include details such as: how someone gets onto your email list, how  you are deleting the name etc.

Answer (score 3):

Several interpretations here.

If 'remove from email list' is the equivalent to 'unsub from group x which is used for a Mailing List' then you should be able to 'remove' them directly from the group.

If it means 'stop sending me any bulk mailings' then you can set their email to "on hold"

if it means 'never ever email you' you can set their record to Do Not Email which should stop even one to one emails from the system